# Getting started with Groovy/Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have got some understanding of Java, I want to learn Groovy/grails. So please suggest me any good website and blogs where I can find documentation, advantage of Groovy over other languages. Is there any site which offers online free course / tutorial for Groovy/grails?

Comment: usinggroovy.blogspot.com :D its one of my blog, however its for groovy and it consist of only 4 post, will see to update here and then :D

Comment: There is no post in this blog !  0))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some "Getting Started" screencasts on the grails.org site as well:

- [Getting Started with Grails - Part 1](http://www.grails.org/screencast/22)
- [Getting Started with Grails - Part 2](http://www.grails.org/screencast/23)
- [Getting Started with Grails - Part 3](http://www.grails.org/screencast/28)

The other screencasts [are available here](http://www.grails.org/screencasts)

Comment: @AdrienBe Thanks for the heads-up!  The grails site recently got updated.  Links changed, so they should now work again :-)

Answer (score 0):

this will be a good start http://www.grails.org/Tutorials

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Getting Started with Grails](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/grails-getting-started), it provides general background of Grails (though some info is not updated).

The screencast mentioned by Tim Yates seems to be good, too.

And I think you definitely should look to series of [GORM Gotchas](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/) blog post. It will benefit you in long term.

Comment: @Hussy: Last but not least, if you have any trouble, just come here at stackoverflow for help :)