# Implementing View from data extraction from a table in grails

Tags: grails

Environment :  grails , oracle DB ,

I have a data table. I need to code to extract this table's data  and show it as tabular data in the View.

1.What different approaches do I have in grails to implement the above?
2.Any references/tutorial links would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're new in Grails, so I suggest you to [Get Start with Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368077/getting-started-with-groovy-grails) first.

You will see that getting a table data and displaying in a `<table>` is pretty straightforward and appears in pretty much all beginners tutorial.

Comment: Michels  Perhaps true ! Im not finding any resource which demos me the above though. so if you could help me with this.. it would help immensely. Pls note ..im very much a beginner in grails groovy

Comment: There's [this book](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/grails-getting-started) that walks you though the basics of Grails. You just need to register to download it.