# How to auto update/refresh in grails view/site?

Tags: grails, web-applications, groovy, xmpp, chat

I am making an xmpp webchat application in Grails. I have a message listener that can log the recieved messages in console. But how can I do this dinamycally in a website ? I am new to webapp development so please dont down vote. I am guessing Ajax but not sure.

My listener:

```
private MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
            // 'from' and 'to' fields contains senders ids, e.g.
            // 17792-1028@chat.quickblox.com/mac-167
            // 17744-1028@chat.quickblox.com/Smack
            String from = message.getFrom().split("@")[0];
            String to = message.getTo().split("@")[0];

            org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message.Type type = message.getType();
            String tajp = type.toString();
            println String.format(">>> Message received (from=%s, to=%s, type=%s): %s", from, to, tajp, message.getBody())

            if (onMessageReceivedListener != null) {
                onMessageReceivedListener.onMessageReceived(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to take a look on the [Events Push](https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push) plugin. With that you can propagate your messages and notify your clients.

You will need:

- Service that notify a new message
- Controller method to call this service
- Ajax request to the controller, sending the user message
- JavaScript to handle incoming messages

> I am new to webapp development

Web development is pretty different from desktop, so I suggest you to slow down to something more easy. [There's other topics on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368077/getting-started-with-groovy-grails) that will introduce you to Grails.

Also, for webdev, it's essential to know about JavaScript, CSS and HTML for your front end.